# Swiftui cmd +VStack doesn’t pull the menu of functions

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm not sure what's wrong, but when I click command+click VStack nothing show up for me at all.

Any suggestions highly appreciated!!

I made sure Canvas opened

Version is 15.1

Have you ever had this kind of an issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [ask] and include a [mre]

Comment: Did you mean to right-click (ctrl+click)? Is that the menu of functions you are talking about?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that Command+clicking on a SwiftUI view would bring up some refactoring options (if your Preview canvas was visible) which Apple called **Code Actions**, whereas other code-based refactoring was available via right-clicking.

However, in Xcode 15 these options were moved to the standard right-click menu, which (as with all versions of macOS) can also be accessed with Ctrl+left click.

From the [Xcode 15 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes) - with my emphasis added:

> The Show Code Actions command has been replaced with Show Quick Actions to quickly access any menu command. By default, Command-clicking a token in the editor now performs Jump to Definition. This can be changed in the Navigation preferences. **Control-clicking a token brings up the standard contextual menu that now contains all the commands that were available in the Code Actions**. (86179596)

The navigation preferences change referred to doesn't allow Code Actions to be reinstated to Command-click, by the way; those actions are permanently moved to the right-click menu. And as ever, some of them are only available if the preview pane is open.